# numpy rolling winodws from numpy table-ish array

Tags: python, numpy

i have the below table-like 6x3 numpy array:

```
array([[1, 4, 1],
       [2, 2, 3],
       [3, 5, 6],
       [4, 8, 5],
       [5, 2, 7],
       [6, 4, 8]])
```

im trying to get rolling windows, say of size 4 (meaning, 4 rows at each window), such as below:

```
array([[[1, 4, 1],
        [2, 2, 3],
        [3, 5, 6],
        [4, 8, 5]],

       [[2, 2, 3],
        [3, 5, 6],
        [4, 8, 5],
        [5, 2, 7]],

       [[3, 5, 6],
        [4, 8, 5],
        [5, 2, 7],
        [6, 4, 8]]])
```

what is a good efficient way of achieving this?

ultimately, i would like to build a function like this:

```
def rolling_windows(arr, windows_size):
    return all windows of size "window_size" of the table-ish np.array "arr"
```

I tried to use `np.lib.stride_tricks`, but unsuccessfuly...

thanks for your help